# How to solve lighting differences on stitching images?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to copy a small image to a bigger image, both images are from the same scene and they are aligned very well. I am using laplacian blending which makes it look seamless. I have one problem that i couldn’t solve yet, which is Illumination problem. Both photos are from same scene and they have taken with very small time difference however there is still some color changes because of lightining differences.  I have tried to solve this problem with using ExposureCompansation class from opencv stitching module, unfortunately i couldn’t make it to work and it is poorly documented and when i search for it i find similar problems asked on stackoverflow and none of them answered yet. So it seems i need to develop my own solution for this Illumination problem and i don’t know where to start. Please tell me where to start.

**Source Image**
[image: Source Image]

**Destination Image**
[image: Destination Image]

**Result Image with problem**
[image: Result Image with problem]

Comment: I recommend you to give the first image without the black circle. Maybe some adventurer would like to try your data-set to explain you how to solve your problem. :)

Comment: You are right, i have changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclude the region that has changed (the stamp) and do a histogram matching to match the histogram of the source image to that of the destination.  The histogram matching will make the colors in the two image match.

Comment: How can i make histogram equalization for two images, it seems histogram equalization applies to single images.

Comment: Sorry I mean histogram matching.  It is a technique that allows you to modify the distribution of one image to match another.

Comment: Some links, examples or explanations on how to do that with opencv would be awesome. Not getting my +1 because of that. :)

Comment: Here's one link - http://www.morethantechnical.com/2010/01/28/recoloring-via-histogram-matching-with-opencv-w-code/ - and I gave him a +1 on your behalf ;-)

Comment: @IanMedeiros I've never used opencv, so can't help you with examples.

Comment: No need to be with opencv. I just asked for a more elaborated answer. Histogram Matching doesn't seen a trivial task. Anyway good link from Roger.